# Using Fubini here to bound the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $V$ and $W$ be bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$,with $V\subset W$ and $d(V,\partial W)>\epsilon$.

Assume $\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)|f(y)|^{p} \ge 0 $  where $\eta(x) = o$ if $|x|\ge \epsilon $

so we can use Fubini theorem here. As follows
$$\begin{array}{l}
\int_{V}\left(\int_{B(x, \epsilon)} \eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)|f(y)|^{p} d y\right) d x 
\leq \int_{W}|f(y)|^{p}\left(\int_{B(y, \epsilon)} \eta_{\epsilon}(x-y) d x\right) d y
\end{array}
$$

The question is how to exchange the order of $y$ and $x$,I try to write the integral domain as indicator function $\chi_A$, such that $A = \{(x,y)|x\in V ,|x-y|<\epsilon\}$ but I still don't know how to get to RHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we have that,
\begin{align}
\int_X \int_Y |F(y)| \chi_{B(x,\epsilon)}(y) G(x,y) dy dx
 \ &= \ 
\int_Y \int_X |F(y)| \chi_{B(x,\epsilon)}(y) G(x,y) dx dy
 \ \\&= \ 
\int_Y |F(y)|  \int_X \chi_{B(x,\epsilon)}(y) G(x,y) dx dy
\end{align}

Now for any (fixed) $y_0 \in Y$, $\chi_{B(x,\epsilon)}(y_0)=1 \  \text{ iff } \ |x-y_0|<\epsilon \  \text{ iff } \ \chi_{B(y_0,\epsilon)}(x)=1$

So last integral is equal to
$$\int_Y |F(y)|  \int_X \chi_{B(y,\epsilon)}(x) G(x,y) dx dy$$

Comment: Hi the $X$ $Y$ are any general shape region does not depend on variable correct?  So the inequalities   $$\begin{array}{l}
\int_{V}\left(\int_{B(x, \epsilon)} \eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)|f(y)|^{p} d y\right) d x 
\leq \int_{W}|f(y)|^{p}\left(\int_{B(y, \epsilon)} \eta_{\epsilon}(x-y) d x\right) d y
\end{array}$$  are two actually,that is we use  inequality $\int_{V\bigcap B(y,\epsilon)} \eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)dx \le \int_{B(y,\epsilon)}\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)dx $here, and $V_\epsilon \subset W$(that is the $V_\epsilon = \bigcup_{x\in V}B(x,\epsilon)$ integral region for variable $y$) here correct?